# How to dissect a log file with Filebeat that has multiple patterns?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have trouble dissecting my log file due to it having a mixed structure therefore I'm unable to extract meaningful data.

A few example lines from my log:

```
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'some username', Password = 'some pass', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'some username', Password = 'some pass', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'some username', Password = 'some pass', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.858  INF  *** BEGINNING OF ARCCore.performARCTask ***
2021.04.21 00:00:00.858  INF  *** BEGINNING OF ARCCore.ProcessTask ***
2021.04.21 00:00:01.266  INF  ARCCore.DCI4ARCSyncLogin: login successfully executed. - No error - DCI4ARCSync-CurrSessions/MaxSessions=17/400 CurrProcesses/MaxProcesses=16/250
2021.04.21 00:00:01.297  INF  ARCCore.DCI4ARCSyncLogin: login successfully executed. - No error - DCI4ARCSync-CurrSessions/MaxSessions=7/400 CurrProcesses/MaxProcesses=7/250
2021.04.21 00:00:08.165  INF  ***  BEGINNING OF SYNC ARC TO DC  ***--->bIsExternal:0
2021.04.21 00:00:08.434  INF  BOC login successfully executed.  - No Error - DCI4ARC-CurrSessions/MaxSessions=24/400 CurrProcesses/MaxProcesses=15/250
2021.04.21 00:00:08.635  INF  BOCVersionNr ==> V16.1.00.00
2021.04.21 00:00:08.804  INF  setEntitySnapshot successfully executed
2021.04.21 00:00:09.453  INF  getSnapshotList successfully executed
2021.04.21 00:00:09.461  INF  getARCVersion: ARCVersionNr ==> V16.0.00.06
```

I wrote a tokenizer with which I successfully dissected the first three lines of my log due to them matching the pattern but fail to read the rest.

My tokenizer pattern:

`%{+timestamp} %{+timestamp}  %{type}  %{msg}: UserName = %{userName}, Password = %{password}, HTTPS=%{https}`

the lines that get read successfully:

2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'some username', Password = 'some password', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'some username', Password = 'some password', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'some username ', Password = 'some password', HTTPS=0

The result:

```
{
  "https": "0",
  "msg": "getBaseData",
  "password": "'20213197'",
  "timestamp": "2021.04.21 00:00:00.843",
  "type": "INF",
  "userName": "'ARC_412_028_01_V01_2021042100000082'"
}
{
  "https": "0",
  "msg": "getBaseData",
  "password": "'20213205'",
  "timestamp": "2021.04.21 00:00:00.843",
  "type": "INF",
  "userName": "'ARC_412_028_01_V01_2021042100000084'"
}
{
  "https": "0",
  "msg": "getBaseData",
  "password": "'20213205'",
  "timestamp": "2021.04.21 00:00:00.843",
  "type": "INF",
  "userName": "'ARC_412_028_01_V01_2021042100000084'"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using https://dissect-tester.jorgelbg.me/ and testing a few different options?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like following. You can define more dissects patterns but if nothing matches at least the log gets through with basic fields. ignore_failure and overwrite_keys might not be needed depending on use case.

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: filestream
    processors:
      - dissect:
          tokenizer: '%{+timestamp} %{+timestamp}  %{type}  %{content}'
          field: message
          target_prefix: ""
          trim_values: left
      - dissect:
          when:
            regexp:
              content: '^getBaseData: .*'
          tokenizer: '%{msg}: UserName = %{userName}, Password = %{password}, HTTPS=%{https}'
          field: content
          target_prefix: ""
          ignore_failure: true
          overwrite_keys: true
processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["content"]
```

Also some sites I found testing regex and filebeat dissect patterns:
https://regex101.com/r/FGheKd/1

https://dissect-tester.jorgelbg.me/